# Как отправить данные с формы React в админпанель Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, cms, wordpress-плагины, nextjs

У меня есть к примеру форма на React (к тому же использую Next.js) и я хочу отправлять данные с нее в админпанель Wordpress. Такая себе Headless CMS. Что бы модератор заходил в админку WP и обрабатывал все заявки. Как сделать это и как правильно их отобразить в админпанели? (У меня есть вот такие поля в форме: first Name, last Name, email, phone number, company name, Topic of Enquiry, Your message (optional). Соответственно нужна какая то кастомная таблица что бы отобразить эти все поля, как это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: StackOverflow так не работает. За вас код тут писать не будут. Приложите свой код - вам помогут.

Comment: Используйте WordPress REST API, если уж так хочется headless.